# Read multiple files python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a new coder in python . I have an issue that I have 360 files, inside each file I have 4 different files with different names. I am looking in `internal_test.txt`.
How I can search inside `internal_test.txt` for all 360 files in my list 
using this code I write but I still need to make one loop to read all the files in output (0-360)

```
import os

Search_Driverdevice='2AA0-E734'
change_Driverdevice='0000000'
sourcepath=os.listdir("path")
sourcepath_Internal_Driver=('C:\\Users\\FIS\Desktop\\test\\InputFiles\\out_put_0\\Internal_use_DRIVES.txt')
print(sourcepath)

for out_put_ in sourcepath:
   # for i in range(len(sourcepath)):

    inputfile=('C:\\Users\\FIS\\Desktop\\test\\InputFiles\\out_put_0\\Internal_use_DRIVES.txt')
    #inputfile =sourcepath
    print('Conversion is ongoing for:'+inputfile)
    with open(inputfile,'r') as inputfile:
        filedata=inputfile.read()
        freq=0
        freq=filedata.count(Search_Driverdevice)
    destinationpath="C:\\Users\\FIS\\Desktop\\test\\OutputFile\\" +out_put_
    filedata=filedata.replace(Search_Driverdevice,change_Driverdevice)
    with open(destinationpath,'w') as out_put_:
        out_put_.write(filedata)
    print("Total%d Record Replaces" %freq)
    print("Data %s that Replaced" %filedata)
```

Comment: *" How I can search inside `internal_test.txt`"*: **You can't**, as this file is not part of your Questions code. Read [mcve]

Comment: Thank you for reply , my file as i name it as (Internal_use_DRIVES.txt) ,y code can go on;y for the first file and i want from him to go to all other directory with same name